# Postgresql ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: json, postgresql

I am writing this code:

```
 select row_to_json(t)

     from (
 select json_agg(A) from (

        select DISCIPLINE.D_ID,DISCIPLINE.D_NAME AS Discipline_Name,

    (
            select json_agg(B) from 
(

            select CATEGORY.C_ID,CATEGORY.C_NAME,

                (
                    select json_agg(C) from 
                    (
                        select SUB_CATEGORY.SC_ID,SUB_CATEGORY.SC_NAME
                        from SUB_CATEGORY 
                        WHERE SUB_CATEGORY .C_ID=CATEGORY.C_ID
                    )C
                ) 
                from CATEGORY
                WHERE CATEGORY.D_ID=DISCIPLINE.D_ID
            )B
        )
        from DISCIPLINE 
    )A
)t
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide an example with some example data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

could be that you inner subquery return more than a row so you should add  limit 1 if you need

```
    select SUB_CATEGORY.SC_ID,SUB_CATEGORY.SC_NAME 
    from SUB_CATEGORY 
    WHERE SUB_CATEGORY .C_ID=CATEGORY.C_ID
    LIMIT 1
```

so

```
    select row_to_json(t)
     from (
      select json_agg(A) from (
       select DISCIPLINE.D_ID,DISCIPLINE.D_NAME AS Discipline_Name, (
        select json_agg(B) from (
         select CATEGORY.C_ID,CATEGORY.C_NAME, (
          select json_agg(C) from (
                select SUB_CATEGORY.SC_ID,SUB_CATEGORY.SC_NAME 
                from SUB_CATEGORY 
                WHERE SUB_CATEGORY .C_ID=CATEGORY.C_ID
                LIMIT 1
          ) C
         ) from CATEGORY WHERE CATEGORY.D_ID=DISCIPLINE.D_ID
        ) B
       ) from DISCIPLINE 
     ) A
    ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data I would guess that one of your `WHERE a = b` clauses is the problem.

If you are doing the `=` comparison of a value with another you have to ensure that there you really have only one value to compare with. So in this case you have to ensure that either in `WHERE SUB_CATEGORY .C_ID=CATEGORY.C_ID` or in `WHERE CATEGORY.D_ID=DISCIPLINE.D_ID` the second term is really one value. Otherwise the equals comparison does not know which value should be taken to compare with.

If there are more than one value:

- Find the error if this should not be
- `LIMIT 1` if it should be the first ID every time (are they ordered? Otherwise this could be very random)
- Use another comparison operator, e. g. the `IN` comparator